# Permitir DLL's não gerenciadas no IIS

Tags: iis, dll

Como configurar o IIS no windows 10 para permitir DLL não gerenciadas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A princípio, não precisa configurar nada. Basta ser visível no PATH do Windows ou no diretório Windows/System32, isso para dll x64. Para as x86, você precisa colocar dentro do diretório Windows/SYSWoW64/System32 e configurar o site do IIS para ser compatível com 32 bits.

É interessante verificar se todas as dependẽncias estão satisfeitas utilizando o utilitário [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: já estão em System32, mesmo assim os erros continuam.

Comment: São dlls 32 ou 64 bits?

Comment: Dependendo do tipo de DLL, pode ser que você tenha que registrar. [como registrar uma dll (Inglês)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897685/how-do-i-register-a-dll-file-on-windows-7-64-bit)

Comment: é 64 bits, eu fiz e diz.. o módulo foi carregado, mas dllregisterserver não foi localizado.

Comment: como você quer acessar essa dll? É uma aplicação ASP, ou é ASP.NET?

Comment: Asp.Net acesso na página web para conectar uma câmera termográfica

Comment: @Lorena apenas confirmando - `regsvr32` precisa ser executado como administrador, caso contrário `dllregisterserver` irá falhar (e, em alguns casos, sileciosamente.)

Comment: @OnoSendai executei como administrador e mesmo assim diz que dllregisterserver não foi encontrado.

Comment: @Lorena Então sua DLL não possui a interface para registro (não é um objeto COM). Pode ser também que você esteja registrando uma DLL 32bits em um ambiente 64 bits ou vice-versa. Se você quiser confirmar, digite `dumpbin /exports 'nomedadll.dll'`.